# grep search for the exact pattern in R

Tags: r

I want to search for the exact match string. I am able to find it but, I don't want a match if the string contains additional details appended to the pattern. For example, in below code I am able to find the match

```
grep("CUST CODE: 123", x = "CUST CODE: 123")
[1] 1
```

But, I don't want below string to get matched or it should avoid the match since there is ADDITIONAL after 123.

```
grep("CUST CODE: 123", x = "CUST CODE: 123 ADDITIONAL")
```

I have used options like ignore.case, Fixed but, that leads matching.

Comment: Why not make an equality test ? `value == "CUST CODE: 123"` or `%in%` if several choices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may place starting `^` and ending `$` anchors around the pattern:

```r
x <- c("CUST CODE: 123", "CUST CODE: 123 ADDITIONAL")
grep("^CUST CODE: 123$", x, value=TRUE)

[1] "CUST CODE: 123"
```